# Jestでモジュールの一部をモックする

Tags: javascript, typescript, テスト, jestjs

Jestを使ったテストの実装で困っています。

**a.ts**

```
export const f1 = () => 'f1';
export const f2 = () => f1();
```

**a.spec.ts**

```
import * as a from './a'

it('f1をstubしたい', () => {
  const f1Spy = jest.spyOn(a, 'f1').mockReturnValue('mocked');
  expect(a.f2()).toBe('mocked');  // Expected:'mocked', Actual:'f1'
  expect(f1Spy).toBeCalled();
});
```

上記実装で、 `expect(a.f2()).toBe('mocked');` のテストが通って欲しいのですが、mockされずにオリジナルの`f1()`が実行されてしまいます。

モジュールの一部をモックする方法はありますか？

---

### 追記

以下のようにf1とf2を別モジュール（別ファイル）にすると意図した動作になりましたが、できればf1とf2を同じモジュールに実装したいのでどなたかご存じの方教えて下さい。

**f1.ts**

```
export const f1 = () => 'f1';
```

**a.ts**

```
import { f1 } from './f1';
export const f2 = () => f1();
```

**a.spec.ts**

```
import * as f1 from './f1'
import * as a from './a'

it('f1をstubしたい', () => {
  const f1Spy = jest.spyOn(f1, 'f1').mockReturnValue('mocked');
  expect(a.f2()).toBe('mocked');
  expect(f1Spy).toBeCalled();
});
```

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51269431/4366193

Comment: @harry0000 ありがとうございます。https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193363/1762538 こちらでもモジュールを分ける方法が紹介されていますね。babelやtscも絡むので一筋縄には行きませんね…

Comment: どうしても分けたくない事情があれば、そちらの回答の **Import the module into itself** の方で記述するのが一案ですかね。